# condition on "if the source code block is tangled"

Tags: tangle, babel

is there a way to query if the current source code block is tangled and if so, to execute e.g. shell stuff depending on if it was or not? I know I can make tangling conditional, but can one also do the other way around?

Comment: What does "if the current source code block is tangled" mean? Does it mean that the tangled file exists? Or something else?

Comment: means just when a block is tangled e.g. C-c C-v t only then execute sth within the block

Comment: You can add an [after-advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html#Advising-Functions)  to the function bound to `C-c C-v t` (that is `org-babel-tangle`).